# iis failed to load resource asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have developped a simple web application in visual studio 2012 and everything works fine.

Using the Publish feature of vs12, i can access the website through local iis but with problems.

Logo image of my application is not shown.

From Console of Chrome i get the following message

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, perhaps you should describe how you're adding the logo to the page (provide the code) and describe the site's structure?

Comment: Do you have only files needed to run this application set? If so probably can't find image cause it wasn't loaded with project

Comment: For some reason, even though i chose to Add All Files, the images were not included. So i did that manually.